# Should I use the MongoId object to identify sub documents?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a schema setup this way:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("5130ea935b51eafc13000032"),
 "items": [
           {
             "id": ???,
             "title": "yes"
           },
           {
             "id": ???,
             "title": "no"
           }
          ]
 }
```

What is the best way to assign unique ids to all subdocuments, throughout the entire collection ?

Should I use the **MongoId()** object ? the PHP's **uniqid()** function ? a simple **increment** ? ... and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is a common, but still a tricky question about the IDs.

First of all, if you have a list of documents embedded, check your subject area. Do those objects have a natural id (Like the books have ISBN number, etc.)? If yes - you could easily flag that as ID and that would be a bit more helpful for you in the code. It will be easier to see the data -- application bond.

In case when the sub-object doesn't have a natural id, you better use the MongoId object - it is already implemented, and you don't have to think about generating a new unique id (even if it is an increment) and manually setting that id to a new object.

Hope that helps. Good luck.